# Lax entropy condition for convex flux and sign of shock speed

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

> Assume that $u$ is an entropy solution to $u_t+\partial_x(A(u))=0$, where $A$ is a non-decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A(0)=0$ and $$A'(u_\ell)>\gamma'(t)=\frac{A(u_\ell)-A(u_r)}{u_\ell-u_r}>A'(u_r)$$ (namely the Lax' entropy condition, where $u_\ell, u_r$ are of the usual meanings). Prove that the shocks travel from left to right if $A$ is convex.

I got frustrated after spending a long time on it (not sure if one is supposed to consider the shock speed $\gamma'(t)$, which is always non-negative since $A$ is non-decreasing). I believe that I missed something here and that there is some very simple way to solve this problem. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is slightly misleading. Indeed, it is assumed that the flux $A$ is convex and increasing. The speed of a shock wave is given by the Rankine-Hugoniot condition
$$
\gamma'(t) = \frac{A(u_\ell) - A(u_r)}{u_\ell - u_r}
$$
so as to ensure that the shock is a weak solution. Since $A$ is convex, the shock must also satisfy the [Lax entropy condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3031222/418542)
$$
A'(u_\ell) > \gamma'(t) > A'(u_\ell)
$$
to be an entropy solution. To prove that $\gamma'(t) > 0$, we use the fact that $A$ is non-decreasing. 
Therefore, admissible shocks propagate to the right if $A$ is convex and non-decreasing (note that $A(0)=0$ is not required). In the case of the inviscid Burgers' equation $A(u) = \frac{1}{2}u^2$, this is only true for $u \geq 0$.